# Align Contents Bottom for form-group in Bootstrap v4

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, forms, bootstrap-4

Right now I am having the issue where my label overflows and wraps around, making the input field not align to the bottom of the div. Is there a simple CSS way to do this?

I have tried position relative/absolute, display inline block + vertical align bottom, etc.

[image]

Any tips / assistance would be very appreciated!!11!1

```
<div class="form-row m-0">
<div class="col-md-6 p-0">
    <div class="col bg-success form-group p-2 m-0 h-100"><label for="theHours"><b>Hours</b></label><input class="form-control" type="text" id="theHours" aria-describedby="hoursHelp"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 p-0">
    <div class="col bg-success form-group p-2 m-0 h-100"><label for="theOrder"><b>Work Order / Notification / Emergency</b></label><input class="form-control" type="text" id="theOrder" aria-describedby="orderHelp"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand, if there isn't enough room, of course it's going to over flow?? The div class="col-md-6" has a width, and if the text doesn't fit in it it will overflow. Do you mean how to make the font size smaller?

Comment: @SheshankShankar I understand that it will overflow. My question is how do I align "Hours" and it's input box to the bottom so that it lines up properly?  Since right now it is staggered.

Comment: Oh I see.. That makes much more sense, thanks

Comment: Have you tried making a table with the first rows as the labels and the second row as the button?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not use the inner `col`. Change the `display` of `col-md-6` columns to **`flex`** and their direction to column. And then align them however you like.

1. **`d-flex`** - change display of column to flex
2. **`flex-column`** - change direction of column to column
3. **`justify-content-end`** - align content of the columns at the end. You can also use **`justify-content-between`**.

I use `col-6` instead of `col-md-6` because `col-md-6` is for screen size bigger than `≥768px` only.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-row m-0">
  <div class="col-6 bg-success form-group p-2 m-0 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
    <label for="theHours"><b>Hours</b></label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="theHours" aria-describedby="hoursHelp">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 p-0 bg-success form-group p-2 m-0 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
    <label for="theOrder"><b>Work Order / Notification / Emergency</b></label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="theOrder" aria-describedby="orderHelp">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzgZXa

Comment: Hey @mahan. I will check this today to see how it works. If so, then I will accept this as the answer. Thank you for your reply!